# How to scrape Ajax Call Data in Div by id in PHP

Tags: php, ajax, dom, curl, web-scraping

I want to **scrape** some data from [webpage](http://www.appliancepartspros.com/whirlpool-light-bulb-8009-ap3607217.html) that is `Cross Reference and Model Information`

I have a script which **scraped** all other data form page.

But as required data is coming from Ajax call in Div by id.

```
<div class="inner" style="overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: scroll; height:300px;" id="xmodellist"><table>
            <tbody><tr>
                <th>Manufacturer</th>
                <th>Model Number</th>
                <th>Description</th>
            </tr>
    
            <tr>
                <td>Amana</td>
                <td><a href="/parts-for-amana-sxd26vw-p1315202w-w.html">SXD26VW</a></td>
                <td>REF - SXS/I&amp;W</td>
            </tr></tbody></table>
    </div>
```

Ajax Code of webpage from [view source](http://view-source:http://www.appliancepartspros.com/whirlpool-light-bulb-8009-ap3607217.html)

```
 $.ajax({
                url: "/partmodellist.aspx?partid=" + partid + "&os=" + os.toString(),
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data) {
                        $('#xmodel1').replaceWith(data);

                        $('#xmodellist').scroll(function () {
                            if (($('tr#trxrefloading').length > 0) && $('#xmodellist').scrollTop() + $('#xmodellist').innerHeight() >= $('#xmodellist')[0].scrollHeight) {
                                os = os + 1;
                                $.ajax({
                                    url: "/partmodellist.aspx?partid=" + partid + "&os=" + os.toString(),
                                    success: function (html) {
                                        if (html) {
                                            if (html.trim().length > 0)
                                            {
                                                $("tr#trxrefloading").before(html);
                                            }
                                            else
                                            {
                                                $('tr#trxrefloading').css("display", "none"); 
                                                $('#xmodellist').unbind();
                                            }
                                        } else {
                                            $('tr#trxrefloading').css("display", "none"); 
                                            $('#xmodellist').unbind();
                                        }
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        });

                    } else {
                        $('xmodel1').css("display", "none"); 
                    }
                }
            });
```

I want to **scrape** all information in that div.

I have attached my [existing code file.](http://www.filehosting.org/file/details/590869/product_scraping_curl_mfgnumber.php) [or this link](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=07688380083487749857)

Please provide suggestion that how can I achieve this.

Comment: FYI it’s __scrape__ (and __scraper__, __scraping__, __scraped__) not scrap

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use CURL to simulation request to get data from partmodellist.aspx rather than **scrape** it or simulate browser behavior by selenium lib.
[What is Selenium?](http://www.seleniumhq.org/)

Answer (score -1):

I was also trying to **scrape** ajax in php and found this:

http://256cats.com/scraping-asp-websites-php-dopostback-ajax-emulation/

I tried to implement it but I'm not a developer so my skills are limited and I am actually trying to do something much simpler than the example shown in the article. By that I mean: I couldn't do it. I also tried contacting the developer with no success.

But it might interest you.